# Postgresql group by show all elements even null

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, pivot, where-clause

I have the following table (sales):

[image]

Query:

```
select product_id, sum(age)
FROM sales
WHERE age > 25
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY product_id
```

The actual result:

[image]

I want to show all *product_id* on the column. If the *age* is <=25 i want to show as 0.
Example, *product_id* 1 will show as 0.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation. The idea is that you should not filter out rows in the `where` clause (since it removes products that have no match before you get a chance to handle them); instead, you can move the filtering logic to the `sum()`:

```
select product_id, coalesce(sum(age) filter(where age > 25), 0) sum_age
from sales
group by product_id
order by product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE

```
select product_id,(CASE WHEN sum(age)<=25 THEN 0 ELSE sum(age) END)
FROM sales
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY product_id
```